# NSKeyedArchiver and NSValue - How to Archive?

Tags: iphone, archive, nskeyedarchiver, cgpoint

How do I archive an array of NSValues ?  What conversions should I make to do this?  It won't archive it as is.

Code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver 
archivedDataWithRootObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:drawingsArray]] 
forKey:@"NSValuesArray"];
```

Error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedArchiver encodeValueOfObjCType:at:]: this archiver cannot encode structs'
```

Array Data:

```
drawingsArray (
    (
    NSPoint: {439, 280},
    NSPoint: {439, 280},
    NSPoint: {439, 287},
    NSPoint: {438.62, 290.104},
    NSPoint: {439, 293}
)
```

)

Comment: According to the documentation, `NSValue` implements the `NSCoding` protocol, so it should work fine.  What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I have posted the code, please see it above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `NSKeyedArchiver`.  Instead, just say `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueArray forKey:@"valueArray"]`.  The archiving will be done automatically.  See if that works.

**EDIT:** I think your specific problem is using `archivedDataWithRootObject:`.  You don't need to use that, since `NSArray` conforms to `NSCoder`--the child objects will also be archived automatically.

Comment: I also have this problem. NSPoint is a struct, NSKeyedArchiver cant encode structs.